# T-SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near '+'

Tags: sql, t-sql

I wanna create a DB, but i want to read instancename since i'm using instance name as my folder name so i wrote my code as:

```
set @instancename = CONVERT( VARCHAR(50),SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName'))
 if @instancename IS NULL
  begin
  set @instancename= 'MSSQLSERVER'  -- MSSQLSERVER if default instance
  end

declare @sql varchar(128)

set @sql= 'CREATE DATABASE [DPO_MainDB] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N''DPO_MainDB_Data'', FILENAME= N''H:\'+@instancename+'\SQLData\DPO_MainDB_Data.MDF'', SIZE = 4MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
LOG ON 
( NAME = N''DPO_MainDB_Log'', FILENAME = N''G:\'+@instancename+'\SQLLogs\DPO_MainDB_Log.LDF'' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
END'
Exec(@sql)
```

but i got this error:
Incorrect syntax near '+'.

I tried many things but still have  this problem. I know that I can use + since i've used it before but i dunno what's wrong with it :( I'll appreciate any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do this using dynamic SQL.  So you will create the sql you want to execute in a variable and then pass that variable to [EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).  So something like:

```
set @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE [DPO_MainDB] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N''MainDB_Data'', FILENAME= N''H:\'+@instancename+'\SQLData\DPO_MainDB_Data.MDF'', SIZE = 4MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
LOG ON 
( NAME = N''MainDB_Log'', FILENAME = N''G:\'+@instancename+'\SQLLogs\DPO_MainDB_Log.LDF'' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
END'

EXEC(@sql)
```

You will be able to reference variables no problem in your @sql assignment.  Notice that i have escaped `'` characters with `''` inside of the @sql variable.

Comment: thank u, i tried it...now i see this error: Incorrect syntax near ')' after exec(sql) ...sorry i'm very beginner to t-sql

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: Hrrm, should work.  I just tried a simplified version of the above code and it ran no problem.  Can you update your question with the new sql that is throwing the error?

Comment: well in  the next line (after exec(sql)) i have a GO which has a red line now and it's saying incorrect syntax error for GO...i think i messed up something

Comment: well for one, 128 is too small for your varchar variable.  I'm not sure if that would cause the problem you are seeing, but try bumping that up to, say, 1000?

Comment: Without seeing all of the SQL it's impossible for me to say what is causing the problem.

Comment: i put an "end" after the exec and it's working now :D Thank u so much for your help :)